# Multiple Commands Produce gRPCCertificates.bundle error on Archive (iOS Xcode 11.1, Firebase SDK)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

In updating to the latest Cocoapods, I updated googleapis pod and encountering the following error on Archiving the build in Xcode 11.1:

```
Multiple commands produce '...iphoneos/gRPCCertificates.bundle'
```

1) Target 'gRPC-gRPCCertificates

2) Target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates

How do I remove the Build target gRPC-C++ certificates? Looking in Build Settings and can't seem to find anything here.

Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Kintsugi Mindful Wellness' do

    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for Kintsugi Mindful Wellness
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Crash'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance'
    pod 'Firebase/Functions'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

    pod 'googleapis', :path=> "."

    pod 'GoogleSignIn'

    ...

    target 'Kintsugi Mindful WellnessTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end

    target 'Kintsugi Mindful WellnessUITests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end

end
```

Older thread mentions updating to the latest pod (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2102) but I've already done so and keep encountering this issue (happens every OS update but keep forgetting where to change this config).

When I use the Legacy Build System, I get more granular errors as follows:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'GRPCClient': '.../Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/.../gRPC-umbrella.h

While building module 'ProtoRPC' imported from /...google/cloud/speech/v1/CloudSpeech.pbrpc.h:6

While building module 'GRPCClient' imported from /.../Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/.../BuildProducts...

In file included from <module-includes>:1:

Parse issue
Could not build module 'GRPCClient'
ProtoRPC.h

While building module 'ProtoRPC' imported from /.../CloudSpeech.pbrpc.h:6:

In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /.../gRPC-ProtoRPC/gRPC-ProtoRPC-umbrella.h:14:

Could not build module 'ProtoRPC'
CloudSpeech.pbrpc.h
In file included from /.../v1/CloudSpeech.pbrpc.m:2
```

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate gRPC certificate bundle can be found in Products.

[image: screenshot of the duplicate bundle in Products]

To remove the duplicate bundle, select Pods and from the Target, just remove one of the certificates (e.g. gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates):

[image]